# thread cancellation in posix threads

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

i am using posix threads        my question is as to whether or not a thread can cancel itself by passing its own thread id in pthread_cancel function?
if yes then what are its implications

also if a main program creates two threads and one of the thread cancels the other thread then what happens to the return value and the resources of the cancelled thread
and how to know from main program as to which thread was cancelled ..since main program is not cancelling any of the threads

i am using asynchronous cancellation

kindly help

Comment: Not quite sure I understand.  Why would a thread want to cancel itself, instead of just pthread_exiting itself?

Answer (score 7):

Q1: Yes, a thread can cancel itself.  However, doing so has all of the negative consequences of cancellation in general; you probably want to use [`pthread_exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_exit) instead, which is somewhat more predictable.

Q2: When a thread has been cancelled, it doesn't get to generate a return value; instead, [`pthread_join`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) will put the special value `PTHREAD_CANCELED` in the location pointed to by its `retval` argument.  Unfortunately, you have to know by some other means that a specific  thread has *definitely* terminated (in some fashion) before you call `pthread_join`, or the calling thread will block forever.  There is no portable equivalent of `waitpid(..., WNOHANG)` nor of `waitpid(-1, ...)`.  (The manpage says "If you believe you need this functionality, you probably need to rethink your application design" which makes me want to punch someone in the face.)

Q2a: It depends what you mean by "resources of the thread".  The thread control block and stack will be deallocated.  All destructors registered with [`pthread_cleanup_push`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cleanup_push) or [`pthread_key_create`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_key_create) will be executed (on the thread, before it terminates); some runtimes also execute C++ class destructors for objects on the stack.  It is the application programmer's responsibility to make sure that all resources owned by the thread are covered by one of these mechanisms.  Note that some of these mechanisms have inherent race conditions; for instance, it is impossible to open a file and push a cleanup that closes it as an atomic action, so there is a window where cancellation can leak the open file.  (Do not think this can be worked around by pushing the cleanup before opening the file, because a common implementation of *deferred* cancels is to check for them whenever a system call *returns*, i.e. exactly timed to hit the tiny gap between the OS writing the file descriptor number to the return-value register, and the calling function copying that register to the memory location where the cleanup expects it to be.)

Qi: you didn't ask this, but you should be aware that a thread with asynchronous cancellation enabled is officially not allowed to do *anything* other than pure computation.  The behavior is undefined if it calls *any* library function other than `pthread_cancel`, `pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED)`, or `pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE)`.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. Yes,thread can cancel itself.

Q2. If one thread cancel another thread , its resources are hang around until main thread 
    join that thread with pthread_join() function(if the thread is joinable). And if the canceled
    thread is not join in main thread resources are free with program ends/terminate.

Q3. I am not sure, but main program don't know which thread was canceled.

Answer (score 0):

thread can cancel any other thread (within the same process) including itself

threads do not have return values (in general way, they can have return status only), resources of the thread will be freed upon cancellation

main program can store thread's handler and test whether it valid or not

Comment: Threads do have return values.  [`pthread_join`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) will place the special value `PTHREAD_CANCELED` in the location pointed to by its `retval` argument when a thread was canceled.

Comment: @Zack agree, but it is not actually a return value, it is exit status, of course sometimes you can use it as return value

Comment: Under normal circumstances, the value placed in that location is the return value from the thread start procedure, so I think it is reasonable to describe it as a return value.

Comment: Also, it's not an integer return status, it is a `void *`.

Comment: @Zack you're right, but I really dont suggest to use anything except integers